# Comparison of existing files not as expected

Tags: java, file

I am trying to compare the contents of a file with a String object.
But even though the contents are same, it is telling that the contents are different and adding the same contents again and again.
For every run of this code, same content is rewritten which is not what I want. Same content should not be rewritten.

```
package fileOperations;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.DataInputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class CompareFiles {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        CompareFiles cf = new CompareFiles();

        String file1 =("new apple") ;
            System.out.println(file1);
            System.out.println("length"+file1.length());
        File f = new File("C:\\Documents and Settings\\newfile.txt");
            cf.compareFiles(file1, f);

    }

    private void compareFiles(String new_content,File f) throws IOException{

        StringBuffer old_content=new StringBuffer();
        String str;
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(f);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

          while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
              System.out.println(str);            
              old_content.append(str);
            }
          fstream.close();
        System.out.println("length "+old_content.length());

        if(!(0==new_content.compareTo(old_content.toString()))){
            createPrivateKey(f, new_content);
        }
    }

    public void createPrivateKey(File privateKeyFile,String keyString ){

        try {
            FileWriter fs = new FileWriter(privateKeyFile);
            fs.write(keyString);
            fs.close();
            System.out.println("Private key file contents added");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to access  private key file and/or config file");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems the string read from file will always be missing EOL characters.

Comment: I have found the issue and the unexpected behavior is as im not taking care of \n character, which is missed due to readline.

Comment: If you have solved the problem, please write up the solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents are the same and the result is as expected. The breakline was not not taken care of i.e., "\n" needed to be appended, before or after-- old_content.append(str);

Answer (score 0):

I would have avoided trying to re-invent the wheel and use [Apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/) - [`FileUtils.contentEquals()`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#contentEquals%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29) to compare two files and [`FileUtils.readFileToString()`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString%28java.io.File%29) to get it as a `String` object

Apache commons is an open source widely used library with very premissive license, so using it is usually a good choice.

P.S. Your bug might be that you are not appending the line-terminator after each line, but it is going to be hard to tell without knowing the contents.

Comment: I need to compare content of a file with a String

Comment: @randeepsp: Then use `FileUtils.readFileToString()` and compare it.

Comment: I was just about to suggest that :)